# Problema con programa hecho con PyQT6. Ejecuto y no me da Salida

Tags: python, pyqt6

El programa (que me tomo 8 días hacerlo leyendo la documentación de PyQt6 y las librerías matemáticas), es una calculadora de derivadas e integrales que tiene como fin permitir al usuario ingresar una expresión matemática y obtener su derivada o integral. El programa también puede mostrar la gráfica de la función resultante si es posible.

El programa consta de dos archivos, uno que define la clase *Calculadora* y otro que define la función *mostrar_grafica_resultado*.

La clase Calculadora tiene varios atributos, incluyendo entrada, operación, procesar, graficar y resultado. El constructor de la clase crea los widgets y los agrega a un layout vertical, y luego conecta el botón procesar a la función *realizar_operacion*.

La clase tiene métodos para calcular la derivada y la integral de una expresión matemática y mostrar el resultado en la etiqueta resultado. Si la expresión resultante es una función, el botón graficar se habilita y la función se almacena en la variable *funcion_grafica*.

La función *mostrar_grafica_resultado* obtiene la expresión matemática y la operación del usuario y crea y muestra la
gráfica de la función resultante.

El error es que no hay salida. Anteriormente era porque no esta bien colocados los bloques que provocaban que interpretara que operación la variable no estuviera definida.

El código del programa esta dividido en dos archivos **`.py`**:

```
 from sympy.plotting import plot
 from sympy import symbols, sympify, diff, integrate, lambdify
 from typing import Any, Tuple
 from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
 from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, 
 QWidget, QComboBox, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QLabel


class Calculadora(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent: Any = None) -> None:
    super().__init__(parent)

    # Definimos la entrada de texto para la expresión matemática
    self.entrada = QLineEdit(self)

    # Definimos la selección de operaciones disponibles
    self.operacion = QComboBox(self)
    self.operacion.addItems(['Derivada', 'Integral'])

    # Definimos el botón de procesamiento de la operación
    self.procesar = QPushButton('Procesar', self)
    self.procesar.clicked.connect(self.realizar_operacion)

    # Definimos el botón de visualización de la gráfica
    self.graficar = QPushButton('Graficar', self)
 self.graficar.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_grafica_resultado)
    self.graficar.setEnabled(False)

    # Definimos la etiqueta de resultado
    self.resultado = QLabel(self)

    # Creamos el diseño de la ventana
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.entrada)
    layout.addWidget(self.operacion)
    layout.addWidget(self.procesar)
    layout.addWidget(self.graficar)
    layout.addWidget(self.resultado)

    self.setLayout(layout)

def calcular_derivada(self, expresion: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    # Definimos la variable x como un símbolo
    x = symbols('x')
    # Convertimos la expresión de texto a una expresión matemática que SymPy pueda manipular
    funcion = sympify(expresion)
    # Calculamos la derivada de la expresión
    derivada = diff(funcion, x)
    # Convertimos la derivada de nuevo a texto
    return str(derivada), str(funcion)

def calcular_integral(self, expresion: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    # Definimos la variable x como un símbolo
    x = symbols('x')
    # Convertimos la expresión de texto a una expresión matemática que SymPy pueda manipular
    funcion = sympify(expresion)
    # Calculamos la integral de la expresión
    integral = integrate(funcion, x)
    # Convertimos la integral de nuevo a texto
    return str(integral), str(funcion)

def realizar_operacion(self) -> None:
# Obtenemos la expresión matemática y la operación que deseamos realizar
    expresion = self.entrada.text()
    operacion = self.operacion.currentText()

# Dependiendo de la operación que se desea realizar, llamamos a la función correspondiente
if operacion == 'Derivada':
    resultado = self.calcular_derivada(expresion)
elif operacion == 'Integral':
    resultado = self.calcular_integral(expresion)
    
# Mostramos el resultado en la etiqueta correspondiente
    self.resultado.setText(resultado[0])
    self.resultado.repaint()

# Habilitamos el botón de graficar si la operación es una función
if "x" in resultado[1]:
    self.graficar.setEnabled(True)
    # Convertimos la función a una función que pueda ser evaluada por NumPy
    self.funcion_grafica = lambdify(x, resultado[1])


 import CalculadoraDerivadaseIntegralesPyQt6

 def mostrar_grafica_resultado(self) -> None:
# Obtenemos la expresión matemática y la operación que 
deseamos realizar
expresion: str = self.entrada.text()
operacion: str = self.operacion.currentText()

# Dependiendo de la operación que se desea realizar, obtenemos 
la función correspondiente
if operacion == 'Derivada':
    _, funcion = self.calcular_derivada(expresion)
elif operacion == 'Integral':
    _, funcion = self.calcular_integral(expresion)

# Almacenamos la función obtenida para su posterior uso en la 
gráfica
x = symbols('x')
y = funcion.subs(x, symbols('x'))
funcion_grafica = lambdify(x, y)

# Creamos la gráfica y la mostramos
plot(funcion_grafica, (x, -10, 10))

# Dependiendo de la operación que se desea realizar, llamamos 
a la función correspondiente
if operacion == 'Derivada':
    resultado = self.calcular_derivada(expresion)
elif operacion == 'Integral':
    resultado = self.calcular_integral(expresion)

# Mostramos el resultado en la etiqueta correspondiente
self.resultado.setText(resultado[0])
self.resultado.repaint()

# Almacenamos la función obtenida para su posterior uso en la 
gráfica
x = symbols('x')
y = sympify(resultado[1])
funcion_grafica = lambdify(x, y)

# Habilitamos el botón de graficar y lo conectamos a la 
función correspondiente
self.graficar.setEnabled(True)
self.graficar.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_grafica_resultado)
```

Comment: me equivoque, lo que sucede es que la indentación que tiene tu código me hizo ver que la variable la tenias fuera pero no es así.

Comment: operacion = self.operacion.currentText()  aquí la defino

Comment: Si puede haga un ejemplo de como deberia de quedar el pedazo del programa que esta con el error en la linea 67 del primer .py y  me dice tambien en la linea 8

Comment: Pero eso no esta adentro del def, que hace que no este afuera y por lo tanto el if no la ve, porque esta afuera?

Comment: La línea `self.graficar.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_grafica_resultado)` necesita un nivel de indentación más para estar dentro de la función... en python no basta con escribir código a continuación del `def myFunction():`, si no que el nivel de indentación es lo que realmente hace que el código esté "dentro" del bloque de la función. Corrige la indentación de tu código y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Ya corregi el codigo y al final no me da salida porque tengo que convertirlo a archivo Exe. Gracias por su colaboracion!